# How to create a trigger that moves deletions to another table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, triggers

I have a MySQL database with a project and a projectover table (projects are completed by employees) and I need to create a trigger that whenever a project is deleted from the project table, it is placed in the projectover table. I was told the syntax for a trigger in MySQL is as follows:

```
CREATE
  [DEFINER = {user| CURRENT_USER }]
  TRIGGER trigger_name trigger_time trigger_event
  ON tbl_name FOR EACH ROW trigger_stmt
```

Using that template I would assume the correct way to do this would be:

```
CREATE
  [DEFINER = {user| CURRENT_USER }]
  TRIGGER project_done trigger_time delete
  ON project FOR EACH ROW insert into projectover
```

Along those lines, I do not know the exact syntax for the action of inserting those records into the new table, and I do not know what the trigger_time means... any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

[This site](http://www.roseindia.net/sql/trigger/mysql-trigger-after-delete.shtml) has a nice example for you.

```
CREATE TRIGGER Employee_Trigger
AFTER delete ON employee
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  insert into employee_log values(old.id,old.first_name,
   old.last_name,old.start_date,old.end_date,
   old.city,old.description,curtime());
 END
```

**Update**

Note that the insert statement can be easier to

[Trigger docs here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html)
[Insert docs here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html)